# Matlab Subsystem change

Tags: matlab, simulink, subsystem

I have this code that is supposed to change the referenced subsystems in a model to normal subsystems, because I have another script that no longer works on matlab 2020, only on 2017, due to the change of the applications libraries to referenced subsystems. When I run it, I get multiple:

```
*** W02293: SIMULINK DATA TYPE RESTRICTIONS:
***         Could not perform min/max logging or overflow detection for signal.
***         The ufix1 Simulink data type  is not supported.
```

Followed by:

```
Error using change (line 4)
Invalid Simulink object handle
```

Anybody know why? I use the version Matlab R2020b with TargetLink 5.1p1

```
refSubsystem = 'subsys20b';
modelName = 'modelRefSubsys20b';
open_system("Application Name");

oldBlock = [ modelName '/Subsystem Reference'];
newBlock = [ modelName '/subsystem'];

% create a copy of the referenced subsystem
add_block('built-in/Subsystem', newBlock)
Simulink.BlockDiagram.copyContentsToSubsystem(refSubsystem, newBlock)

% Retrieve useful info from the old block
t1 = get_param(oldBlock, 'Portconnectivity');
t2 = get_param(oldBlock, 'PortHandles');
t3 = get_param(newBlock, 'PortHandles');

% delete old lines
h = get_param(oldBlock, 'LineHandles');
ni = numel(h.Inport);
no = numel(h.Outport);
delete_line(h.Inport);
delete_line(h.Outport);

% create connections to new block
for i=1:numel(t2.Inport)
    srcBkhdl = t1(i).SrcBlock; % source block handle
    srcNm = getfullname(srcBkhdl); % source block name
    srcBkPts = get_param(srcNm, 'PortHandles'); % source block port handles
    srcPt = srcBkPts.Outport(t1(i).SrcPort+1); % source port
    dstPt = t3.Inport(i); % destination port
    add_line(modelName, srcPt, dstPt);
end

% create connections from new block
for i=1:numel(t2.Outport)
    dstBkhdl = t1(ni+i).DstBlock; % dest block handle
    dstNm = getfullname(dstBkhdl); % dest block name
    dstBkPts = get_param(dstNm, 'PortHandles'); % dest block port handles
    dstPt = dstBkPts.Inport(t1(ni+i).DstPort+1); % dest port
    srcPt = t3.Outport(i); % src port
    add_line(modelName, srcPt, dstPt);
end

% copy to same position
pos = get_param(oldBlock, 'position');
set_param(newBlock, 'position', pos);

% remove old block
delete_block(oldBlock);

% save changes
save_system(modelName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar error wanting to revert Referenced Subsystems to simple Subsystems. In my case however, I did not want to do that programmatically.

I use MATLAB2021a and had a project initializing the Search Paths.

Removing the Referenced Subsystem link from the Block Parameters raised:

```
Invalid Simulink object handle
```

and prevented me to save the model.
The workaround that I found was:

1. To open the model without loading my project. Not loading the project prevented the Referenced Subsystem from loading since it couldn't find its referenced file. In someone else's case, one could simply move the referenced file outside of your Search Path.
2. Remove the link to the referenced file. I found that doing this after failing to load did not cause the same error.
3. Once the link removed, it is safe to open said referenced file, copy its content and paste it in the now simple subsystem block.
4. Save

I am aware that you wanted to perform this programmatically and I hope this helps you or someone else. Keep in mind, I am no expert. I simply messed around and found something that worked for me.